# Design of a simple progress bar to cout goes from 0->100% instantly at the end in C++

Tags: c++, progress-bar, cout

I would like to make a very basic progress indicator by printing an 'X' char to cout every time a loop progresses another 10%. I am trying to do this as shown in the code pasted below, but it doesn't seem to be working - when really it seems it should.

It's supposed to display steady progress throughout the loop, but instead I get all the X's coming at once after the loop has finished. This is not because the loops are completed too quickly for me to perceive. To verify this you can add an extra 'F' to "TOTAL" to increase the duration of the looping substantially, and you'll see it's not just a question of perception.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

```
#include <iostream>
#define TOTAL 0xFFFFFFF
using namespace std;

int main(void) {

    //Make a counter for counting loops
    double counter = 0;
    // Set it to trigger after each 10% of progress
    double counterMax = TOTAL / 10;

    cout << "Starting now..." << endl;

    for (double i = 0; i < TOTAL; i++) {
        // Do something... anything
        i++;
        i--;
        // Increment the counter
        counter++;
        // Print an X when the counter exceeds the 10%
        // trigger point, and then reset the counter.
        if (counter > counterMax) {
            cout << 'X';
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
    cout << endl << "Done!";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should add `cout.flush();` after `cout << 'X';`.

Comment: Alternately, `cout << 'X' << flush;`

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System input/output calls are usually slow operations.  To increase the efficiency of programs, input and output streams are often buffered, to reduce the number of calls to the operating system.

When a program needs "non-buffered" output, one solution is to use the buffered output functions, and simple "flush" the output to ensure the operating system processes any output which has been queued in any buffers.

When the output buffer is filled, or when the stream is closed, it is automatically flushed.  The standard output is also automatically flushed by certain sequences, like `endl`.  But you can trigger a flush of the standard output at any point by called `cout.flush()` or by using the `flush` manipulator, like:

```
cout << 'X' << flush;
```